# Replacing text using regex in a list of strings in a dataframe

Tags: python, regex

I have a dataframe of text where I want to replace the text of some substrings. For example:

```
"[' Foods are adequately protected from\\n contamination during handling and storage.', ' Food handler hygiene and hand washing is\\n properly followed.', ' Foods are cooked, cooled and stored at\\n proper temperatures.', ' Garbage and/or waste is properly stored\\n and removed.', ' Pest control practices are properly maintained.', ' Equipment and utensils are properly cleaned,\\n sanitized and maintained.', ' Food premise is properly maintained in a clean\\n and sanitary condition.']"
```

I want to replace '\n' with ''.

```
[sub.replace('\\n', '') for sub in abc_test]
```

where abc_test is just the first row of the dataframe content. When I apply this function the result turns out to be different than what I was hoping for.

```
['[',
 "'",
 ' ',
 'F',
 'o',
 'o',
 'd',
 's',
 ' ',
 'a',
 'r',
 'e',
 '
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: may be `abc_test.replace('\\n','')` ?

Answer (score 0):

The point here is that your strings contain combinations of a backslash and `n` char, not newline chars. Thus, neither `"\n"` (an LF, line feed, char) nor `"\\n"` (a `\n` regex escape that matches a newline, LF, char) work.

You can use

```
df['res'] = df['text'].str.replace(r"\\n", "")
```

Pandas test:

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'text': [' Foods are adequately protected from\\n contamination during handling and storage.', ' Food handler hygiene and hand washing is\\n properly followed.', ' Foods are cooked, cooled and stored at\\n proper temperatures.', ' Garbage and/or waste is properly stored\\n and removed.', ' Pest control practices are properly maintained.', ' Equipment and utensils are properly cleaned,\\n sanitized and maintained.', ' Food premise is properly maintained in a clean\\n and sanitary condition.']})
>>> df['res'] = df['text'].str.replace(r"\\n", "")
>>> df
                                                text                                                res
0   Foods are adequately protected from\n contami...   Foods are adequately protected from contamina...
1   Food handler hygiene and hand washing is\n pr...   Food handler hygiene and hand washing is prop...
2   Foods are cooked, cooled and stored at\n prop...   Foods are cooked, cooled and stored at proper...
3   Garbage and/or waste is properly stored\n and...   Garbage and/or waste is properly stored and r...
4    Pest control practices are properly maintained.    Pest control practices are properly maintained.
5   Equipment and utensils are properly cleaned,\...   Equipment and utensils are properly cleaned, ...
6   Food premise is properly maintained in a clea...   Food premise is properly maintained in a clea...
```